# Edit Word Tooltips

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, tooltip

How I can edit the box that comes out when you move the cursor over an icon. Within the menus of Word or a macro. I have tried all the options offered by Word, even Visual Basic scripts. I searched but have not been successful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2007 or Word 2010, the tooltips (popup text on toolbar icons) are specified in the Office XML file.

1. Put your macros in a .docx or .dotx file that will be an addin.
2. Use the tool described [here](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/25/customuieditor.aspx) to add an XML part to that .docx or .dotx document.
3. In the XML part, describe whatever buttons or other controls you may want on a toolbar.  The documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202.aspx) tells you about the XML you can use.  To change the tooltip, set the `screentip` and `supertip` fields.  An example XML file is:

   ```
   <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
     <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
       <tabs>
          <!-- Your tabs and controls go here -->
          <tab id="CustomTab" label="My Tab">
            <group id="SampleGroup" label="Sample Group">
              <button id="Button1" label="My Large Button" 
                size="large" onAction="ThisDocument.MyButtonMacro" 
                screentip="***The text you want to change*** (above the line)" 
                supertip="***The text you want to change*** (below the line)" />
            </group>
          </tab>
       </tabs>
     </ribbon>
   </customUI>
   ```

   and you can change any of the text in double-quotes `"..."`.

[Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx) of the MSDN article has a reference for all the fields you can set.